# Como adiciono mais de um domínio neste alerta?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguém pode me ajudar, pois consigo adicionar somente um domínio, e quando tento colocar mais de 1 URL não funciona. Se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato!

```
    if((window.location.href).indexOf('DOMÍNIO') >= 0){
      }else{ // Como faço para adicionar mais de um DOMÍNIO ?
   }
```

Edit:

Eu fiz dessa forma e o alerta funcionou somente no dominio 1, quando abro o segundo site aparece o alerta, você pode me ajudar porque o dominio 2 não está sendo reconhecido? Segue abaixo o modelo:

```
var listaDominios = ["http://www.dominio1.com", "http://www.dominio2.com"];
var dominioValido = listaDominios.find(function(dominio){
    return window.location.href.indexOf(dominio) > -1;
});    

if(dominioValido) {
}else{
alert('Site não autorizado');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melhor criar um array de domínios para evitar `else if`'s:

```
var dominios = ["DOMINIO1", "DOMINIO2"];

if(window.location.href.indexOf(dominios) > -1) {
  // faça qualquer coisa
}
```

**Edit:** So me apercebi agora que o objetivo é ter apenas o domínio e nao o URL inteiro. Segue um exemplo:

```
var listaDominios = ["DOMINIO1", "DOMINIO2"];
var dominioValido = listaDominios.find(function(dominio){
    return window.location.href.indexOf(dominio) > -1;
});    

if(dominioValido) {
  // faça qualquer coisa
}
```

**Edit2:** Por falha minha, deves usar o `Array.prototype.some` em vez de `Array.prototype.find`, e usar `hostname` como sugerido pelo @MoshMage:

```
var listaDominios = ["DOMINIO1", "DOMINIO2"];
var dominioValido = listaDominios.some(function(dominio){
    return window.location.hostname.indexOf(dominio) > -1;
});    

if(dominioValido) {
  // faça qualquer coisa
} else {
  alert('Site não autorizado');
}
```

**Nota:** Neste caso sub-dominios irão fazer *match* com super-dominio na lista, se quiseres comparar ao nivel do sub-dominio, substituis `window.location.hostname.indexOf(dominio) > -1` por `window.location.hostname === dominio`.

Comment: Tem como rever o edit da pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Tens que ter, como o @Roberto diz, uma lista de dominios:

`var dominios = ["dominio1.com", "dominio2.com"];`

depois uma simples iteração nessa array, junta com o [`window.location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location) diz-te se estás (ou nao) nesse dominio:

`var dominioNaLista = dominios.some(function(dominio) { return dominio.indexOf(window.location.hostname) > -1 })`

depois desta operação, `dominioNaLista` é um `boolean` com o valor positivo ou negativo, conforme estás ou nao num dominio contido na lista.

[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) é um metodo de `Array` que retorna `true` à primeira vez que a condição do callback é verdadeira.

`window.location.hostname` (`hostname` é a palavra chave aqui) retorna o dominio da janela activa (`href` retorna *todo o url*) - o valor de `window.location.hostname` deste site, pex, é `pt.stackoverflow.com`